# Spark Streaming progress partitions independently

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a scenario where we have partitioned our input Kafka topics by Account Number. Each partition directly writes to DB and have no dependency on the each other.

Currently, even if one partition completes the processing in 5 seconds, it has to wait for the slowest partition to complete to start processing the next batch. Let's say slowest partition takes 30 seconds then the partition that completed within 5 seconds has to remain idle for 25 seconds.

Is there a way to set up micro batch where in we process each partition sequentially and independent of other partitions? In my earlier e.g the partition that completed the batch in 5 seconds should pick up the next batch right away without being idle for 25 seconds.

Comment: do a proper repartition on uniquely distributed key.. check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63558408/spark-optimization-joins-very-low-number-of-task-oom/63564686#63564686

Comment: @kavetiraviteja Thanks for your response but not the solution I am looking for.